# Go: Read a Command Line Flag from a File

Tags: go, command-line-interface

When creating a command line program in Go, is there a way (either provided by the core libraries, or a widely accepted practice) to implement a command line flag that reads its contents from a file?

If that's not clear, I'm thinking of something like the `@` symbol in the command line `curl` program.  Many of curl's arguments allow you to do something like this to read a flag's value in from a file

```
# setting the value 
curl --data-binary '{...}' http://example.com

# setting the value by reading from a file
curl --data-binary @path/to/data.txt http://example.com
```

Does go have any code for automatically implementing these sorts of flags?  I've read through the official docs and [didn't see anything obvious](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/), but I'm still getting the hang of navigating those docs.

If there's nothing official, is there a de-facto standard "better flags" library provided by someone in the go community that includes this functionality?

Or is it down to an individual programmer to create a string flag, scan it for the @, and handle reading the file's contents in myself?

Comment: While there are some other config/flag packages in circulation, I would wager that the `@file` syntax is uncommon enough that there isn't a widely used implementation. It's certainly not hard to implement, and most go projects would rather a simple function over an added dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[flag.Value](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Value) allows you to implement arbitrary flag behaviour:

```
package main

import (
        "flag"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "strings"
)

type T string

// String implements flag.Value
func (t *T) String() string {
        return string(*t)
}

// Set implements flag.Value
func (t *T) Set(maybeFilename string) error {
        if !strings.HasPrefix(maybeFilename, "@") {
                *t = T(maybeFilename)
                return nil
        }

        filename := maybeFilename[1:]
        b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }

        *t = T(string(b))
        return nil
}

func main() {
        var t T
        flag.Var(&t, "data-binary", "(description)")
        flag.Parse()
        fmt.Println(t)
}
```